# Proving $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}$ from the definition

Tags: limits, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$
Given an $\epsilon$, I need to find $\delta$ so that $|x| < \delta \implies \left \lvert \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x^2} - \frac{1}{2} \right \rvert < \epsilon$. I can't figure out how to work backwards to $\delta$. I have:
\begin{align*}
 \left \lvert \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x^2} - \frac{1}{2} \right \rvert & = \left \lvert \frac{x^2}{x^2(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2})} - \frac{1}{2} \right \rvert \\
& = \left \lvert \frac{2 - 1(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2})}{2(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2})} \right \rvert \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \left \lvert \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}}  \right \rvert \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \\
& < \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}}
\end{align*}
The result is true provided that $\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \leq \epsilon$. The only quantity I can control is $|x|$, but it is nowhere to be found in this expression. I can write it in by noticing that $x^2 = |x|^2$, but that only "artificially" works in $\delta$ without a lear end in sight.

Should that be my next step, or did I miss a more simple estimate?

Comment: Rationalize the numerator

Comment: So I multiply by $\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}$?

Comment: The conjugate has a plus, but that's the idea. And I meant the original expression.

Comment: I did that in the first equality, though, multiplying by $\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}}$. Do I need to do it again?

Comment: There should be a + in the denominator then. That should make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I edited the attempt and reduced it to finding $\delta$ such that $\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} < \epsilon$. But I run into the same problem: no place to use $\delta$.

Comment: Note, if you call $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x}$ then the limit is $\frac{f(0)-f(x^2)}{x^2}=-f'(0)=\frac 12$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$. You want to see when ${1 - u \over 1 + u} < \epsilon$. This is equivalent to
$$1 - u < \epsilon + \epsilon u$$
Equivalently,
$$1 - \epsilon < u(\epsilon + 1)$$
This is the same as
$$u > {1 - \epsilon \over 1 + \epsilon}$$
Squaring, this becomes
$$1 - x^2 > \bigg({1 - \epsilon \over 1 + \epsilon}\bigg)^2$$
Solving for $|x|$, we get
$$|x| < \sqrt{1 - \bigg({1 - \epsilon \over 1 + \epsilon}\bigg)^2}$$
These steps are reversible, so the expression on the right above can be used as your $\delta$.

Comment: This is very helpful. I could be wrong, but doesn't the squaring function only preserve an inequality $x < y$ if $x,y$ are non-negative? How do we know that the inequality sign doesn't flip after squaring both sides?

Comment: In the case at hand, as long as $\epsilon < 1$, ${1 - \epsilon \over 1 + \epsilon}$ is positive, and as long as $|x| < 1$, $1 - x^2 > 0$, so this issue won't come up... $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ can be assumed to be less than $1$ in such an argument.

Comment: I understand requiring $\delta < 1$, but why can we can take $\epsilon < 1$ if the goal is to prove the statement for all $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: Because if you want to find the $\delta$ for some $\epsilon \geq 1$ you can use the $\delta$ corresponding to say $\epsilon = {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: So it wouldn't matter if that $\delta$ "depended" on that $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ because it's, ultimately, just a real number? I'm having trouble understanding how $\delta$ would vary as $\epsilon$ grows larger.

Comment: If for any $\epsilon \geq 1$ you use the $\delta$ corresponding to $\epsilon = {1 \over 2}$, then if $|x| < \delta$, you have $|f(x) -{1 \over 2}| < {1 \over 2} < \epsilon$, so you're good.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Based on the assumption that $0 < |x| < \delta \leq 1$, we deduce that
\begin{align*}
0 < |x| < \delta & \Rightarrow 0 < x^{2} < \delta^{2}\\\\
& \Rightarrow 1 - \delta^{2} < 1 - x^{2} < 1\\\\
& \Rightarrow \sqrt{1 - \delta^{2}} < \sqrt{1-x^{2}} < 1\\\\
& \Rightarrow 1 + \sqrt{1 - \delta^{2}} < 1 + \sqrt{1 - x^{2}} < 2\\\\
& \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} < \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{1-\delta^{2}}}\\\\
& \Rightarrow 0 < \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} - \frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{1-\delta^{2}}} - \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Consequently, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x^{2}} - \frac{1}{2}\right| & = \left|\frac{1 - (1-x^{2})}{x^{2}(1 + \sqrt{1-x^{2}})} - \frac{1}{2}\right|\\\\
& = \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} - \frac{1}{2}\\\\
& < \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-\delta^{2}}} - \frac{1}{2} = \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: This is very helpful. I will work on this more. Thank you.